# 404 Redirect when there are too many segments

Tags: conditionals, redirects, 404, segments

Having some issues forcing a 404 redirect when there are too many segments. Here is the page I am working on http://syntropy.highimpact.com/case-studies/aurora-flight-sciences/

I'm using the following code on the "case-studies" template:

```
{if segment_3 != ''}
  {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

I thought doing this would force a redirect for any segments after segment 2. For instance, http://syntropy.highimpact.com/case-studies/aurora-flight-sciences/another-segment/ should be forcing a redirect, but instead it seems to be trying to load a page.

All of the other 404 redirect conditions are working fine. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe just try `{if segmemt_3}` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Try some debugging to help. Add this code block to your template:

```
{site_url} / {segment_1} / {segment_2} / {segment_3}

{if segment_3}
    Condition 1 works <br><br>
{/if}

{if {segment_3}}
    Condition 2 works <br><br>
{/if}

{if "{segment_3}"}
    Condition 3 works <br><br>
{/if}

{if segment_3 != ''}
    Condition 4 works <br><br>
{/if}

{if {segment_3} != ''}
    Condition 5 works <br><br>
{/if}

{if "{segment_3}" != ''}
    Condition 6 works <br><br>
{/if}
```

Comment: None of these seem to work. Wondering if it has something to do with the template routing that I have set up. For this template I am using /case-studies/{title:alpha_dash}

Comment: Are you sure which template is being loaded if you have a 3rd segment?

Comment: So, if I add a slash in front of 404 it redirects to that page - it's just won't do the typical 404 redirect for a bad url. `{if segment_3 != ''}{redirect="/404"}{/if}`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it clean and simple. Install [Resource Router](https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) and then add conditions like this to your config file, a lot faster (it's processed before templates), all in one place, keeps your templates clean and far better/thorough handling.

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'case-studies/:any/:all'      => $router->set404()
);
```

Read the docs, there's so much that can be caught and done.